# BaseActivity with common toolbar and menuItems activities can not catch onMenuItemClick

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I've the base activity where all toolbar initializations and options menu  are done, the activities extending the base can not fire onitemclick

In the base i have

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MenuItem refresh;

public Toolbar getToolbar() {
  return toolbar;
}

public MenuItem getRefresh() {
  return refresh;
} 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
  refresh = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
  refresh.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_view);
  return true;
}

@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      onBackPressed();
      break;
  }
  return false;
}

 @Override
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

switch (mState) {
  case Const.STATE_IDLE:
    refresh.setVisible(true);
    break;
  case STATE_WORKING:
    refresh.setVisible(false);
    break;
  default:  
    refresh.setVisible(true);
    break;
}

return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

In one of the activites I handle it like

```
       public class CommentsActivity extends BaseToolbarActivity
        {
         @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         return true;
         }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_refresh){
            setState(Const.STATE_WORKING);
            showMsg(contentRoot,"oops");
           return true;
          }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
      }
```

**but the click items won't fire**

Comment: why do you even implement your logic of menus like that>

Comment: @CaspainCaldion every activity uses the same menu items some don't where it's supposed to be hidden but can not do that as well. Or what do you mean by "like that"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I came to realize that since I was setting a custom layout for my items (useful for animations) an option menu with a custom view that is either set in the xml or dynamically using

```
 item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_lay);
```

Just like my problem above **the menu item can never be invoked by the normal onOptionsItemSelected listener** so the way to make it work is to implement onClickListener on the item's custom View so in my case the way to make it invoke is by

```
        @Override
          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getRefresh.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {   
                //refresh some data
               }
           });
        return true;
       }
```